# Unix: making change to .profile file

Tags: macos, unix, .profile

I am running MAC OS X.

I added a new alias to my .profile. Now, when I open a terminal window, I get a message saying  that the alias cannot be found. Do I have to do some sort of exporting to get the change to my .profile to take affect?

As requested, my .profile.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/local/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/local/lib

alias sl='ls'
alias pwd='echo -n `pwd` | pbcopy'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked that you are using `bash` (or `ksh`) which reads `.profile` and not `tcsh` (the default shell on MacOS X) which does not read `.profile`?

Do any other commands in your profile get executed?

---

The alias not working is:

```
alias pwd='echo -n `pwd` | pbcopy'
```

The issue there is: what command is executed when the

```
`pwd`
```

is executed -- oops; it's the alias?  Try:

```
alias pwd='echo -n $(/bin/pwd) | pbcopy'
```

We could also argue that you can use just:

```
alias pwd='/bin/pwd | pbcopy'
```

Comment: Yes, the first alias works. The second one is the new one that I just added today.

Answer (score 1):

You need to source your profile:

`source .profile`

Answer (score 0):

If you're running leopard or snow leopard then you should put the alias into .bash_login, not .profile.

That's if you're using bash of course, which Mac OS X does by default I believe.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the back ticks there. Where is the .profile file? I can't find mine. I had never used it and putting one in my home directory didn't work.